# accessing a member in a class as a string PHP

Tags: php

in PHP, can we do the following ?

```
class a{
    public $id;
}
```

can we access this field with something like this,

```
$x='id';
$aObj=new a();
$aObj->$x=1;//or $aObj->"id"=1
```

Comment: did you tried ? `$aObj->{$x}`

Comment: [TIAS](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=TIAS)

Comment: are you asking if it is possible OR are you asking because it didn't work for you? You should really test before you ask question here. And yes it is possible.

Comment: Your question implies this does not work, but the code you have posted works OK as is... `$aObj->$x=1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible:

```
class a {
    public $id;

    function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }
}

$x = 'id';
$aObj = new a();
$aObj->$x = 500;

echo $aObj->id, " ", $aObj->getId();
```

gives: `500 500` (Tested with PHP 5.3)

Comment: This is _any_ version of PHP, including PHP 4 (providing the class definition is made compatible).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, but it's discouraged.

To use something like `$aObj->"id"=1` just put the name into brackets

`$aObj->{"id"} = 1;`

If you're asking WHY is this discouraged, that's easy: It's unpredictable, unmaintainable.

Comment: "it's discouraged" - do you have a reference? Note that if the property name is held in a variable (as in the OP) then the curly braces are note required.

Comment: @w3d It's unpredictable, unmaintainable.